# How to quickly uplevel properties in a dict in python?

Tags: python

Say i have this dictionary in python:

```
{'a': {'asuba':'1','asubb':'2'},'b':{'bsuba':'1','bsubb':'2'}}
```

What is the easiest/quickest way to uplevel say key "a" so that my resulting dictionary is:

```
{'asuba':'1','asubb':'2','b':{'bsuba':'1','bsubb':'2'}}
```

Comment: What do you do if you have a key conflict?

Comment: Assume there is no key conflict. Or override with whatever gets picked up last?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Better than an `update` followed by a `del`:

```
d.update(d.pop(k))
```

This avoids issues if the value of `k` contains a key equal to `k` itself (if you `update`, then `del`, the value's key would overwrite the parent's, then get deleted incorrectly when the `del` happens). By `pop`ing first, the entry for `k` is removed before we add the key/value pairs for `k`'s value, so no conflict can occur.

Comment: This is a really nice solution. Didn't know you could pop.

Comment: @mwm314: Yar, `dict.pop` and `dict.setdefault` are two methods more people should know; they're both extremely useful for performing atomic insertions and removals (technically, not thread safe for `setdefault` if the key isn't a built-in type, but still useful for logically atomic operations).